# Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar"

Tags: android, androidx

When I upgrade Androidx，I have a problem as below:

> No pending exception expected: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.alpha.lagouapk-hKiBdzRnFfV_fBa3ll3GWg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.alpha.lagouapk-hKiBdzRnFfV_fBa3ll3GWg==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.alpha.lagouapk-hKiBdzRnFfV_fBa3ll3GWg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /product/lib]]

Comment: Are you using ContextCompat anywhere in your code? Also, could you please share your build.gradle file (both of them if you have two)

Answer (score 0):

The class renamed to `androidx.core.content.ContextCompat`, see [the specs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat?hl=en). You need to change the old references to the new ones.